# Importing our own modules in haskell

Tags: haskell, module

I have the following code, and I only want to export only  sphereVolume and sphereArea  function from my module.

```
module Geometry  
    ( sphereVolume
    , sphereArea  
    ) where  

 sphereVolume :: Float -> Float  
 sphereVolume radius = (4.0 / 3.0) * pi * (radius ^ 3)  

 sphereArea :: Float -> Float  
 sphereArea radius = 4 * pi * (radius ^ 2)  

 cubeVolume :: Float -> Float  
 cubeVolume side = cuboidVolume side side side  

 cubeArea :: Float -> Float  
 cubeArea side = cuboidArea side side side  

 cuboidVolume :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float  
 cuboidVolume a b c = rectangleArea a b * c  

 rectangleArea :: Float -> Float -> Float  
 rectangleArea a b = a * b
```

When I write `import Geometry` in the ghci I get the following error

```
<no location info>:
Could not find module `Geometry':
  it is not a module in the current program, or in any known package
```

I made sure that they are in the same directory and with the same filename as the module. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not `import` in ghci. Just use the usual

```
:l Geometry
```

Answer (score 3):

As Franky says, you can use `:l Geometry` in order to work with your code in GHCi. But you can ony have one module loaded (with `:l`) at a time. what if you have written several modules that you want to be able to work with simultaneously? Then you need to `import` them.

In order to be able to `import Geometry` from within GHCi, you need to install it. The easiest way to do that is using cabal. Here is a [guide](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program).